# How can I use Angular flex-layout to create a left justified grid but have the whole grid centered on the screen?

Tags: angular, flexbox, angular-material

I am trying to use Angular flex-layout create a grid of images that is left justified, but I want the whole grid to be centered on the screen. The problem is that I can only center it row by row, which makes the the last one not left justified. I think I need a way to get the container to shrink to the size of the content but `display: inline-block` is not doing it.

See images:

[Left justified, but not centered on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzGKs.png) aka fxLayoutAlign="start center"

[Centered on the screen, but not left justified](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o26yg.png) aka fxLayoutAlign="center center"

[Paint Mockup of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPikR.png)

Here is my code:

```
* {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gallery {
  display: inline-block;
}

.tile{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```
<div class="gallery" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="start center">
  <div class='tile' *ngFor="let number of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you add a image of what you want as last output.

Comment: @shashanksharma Sure, I added a paint mockup with annotations

Comment: keep it left align but add inner left-right padding to main div.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution or alternative for your question?

Comment: @JuanPabloMorenoMartín Your second option was pretty close to what I needed. I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the galery element is [positioned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) relative, fixed, absolute, or sticky. And adjust the margins by "left and transform".

CSS:

```css
.tile{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.gallery {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery" fxLayout="row wrap">
  <div class="tile"  fxLayoutAlign="start center" *ngFor="let number of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]"></div>
</div>
```

**See the example working here:** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-how-can-i-use-angular-flex-layout-to-create-a-left-just)

**[Edited]**

I have edited my answer to show what would be the best option, as is well discussed in the comments in this answer, the flexible format is probably not the easiest to achieve what is asked, my suggestion is to make the squares self-adjusting and it would be more visually pleasing to the user.

I hope one of my 2 options can help you.

CSS:

```css
.galery{
  margin-left: 50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%);

  display:grid;
  grid-template-columns:repeat(auto-fit, minmax(100px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.title{
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="galery">
  <div class="title" *ngFor="let number of [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11]"></div>
</div>
```

**See the example working here:** [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-card-centered-auto-adjustable)

Comment: Had a look at this, the problem occurs at the snapping points, i.e. Column count goes from 4 to 3, there the flex box does not shrink immediately. check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4kobsf/. 

Documentation: 
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/API-Documentation
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/wiki/Declarative-API-Overview

Comment: The way I did it, I think that the best way to center the elements, the other option is to put the width of the boxes adjustable depending on the screen.

Comment: Agree there is no easy way to solve this in flex format, probably pure bootstrap card grid driven component with responsive item count determination may work.

Had done that in the past but need to dig the code up

Comment: I have edited my answer to show how to achieve this without flexbox, I think it is the best option, although it does not conform to what the OP really asks.